# Probability of choosing different numbers

Tags: probability

Person $A$ chooses $60$ numbers randomly from $1-100$. Person $B$ chooses $30$ numbers from $1-50$ also randomly. I wish to find the expected value of the number of numbers person $A$ chose but person $B$ didn't. I though I should find an indicator and then define a random value which is a sum of it, but I couldn't figure out what it could be. It isn't Bernoulli, non any other distribution I know of (as the probability increases with each choice of person $B$ not in any way familiar to me). I can of course calculate it manually, but I'm wondering if there is any elegent way (I'm pretty sure there is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution). Supposing to be in $A$'s shoes, we want to determine how many numbers $A$ draws that weren't drawn by $B$. Following Wikipedia notation, you have $K=70$, since there are 70 balls that weren't drawn by $B$, $n=60$ is the number of draws made by $A$ and $N=100$ is the population size. The $k$ variable is what you are looking for.